# Scroll to a specific area of an image map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a store directory page that has a list of all stores on the left and five maps on the right. The idea is that when you hover a store on the left, the map will automatically scroll to the corresponding location area.

Each area has a unique idea, such as hotspots-image-520-area-5. So my thought was to simply use scrollTop on hover, but it is not working. You can view the my test page at https://cmxserv03.com/somerset/directory-test/.

Here is the code I am using as well. It will scroll to the top of the map container but not to the individual map areas.

```
$("#Aveda").hover(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#hotspots-image-520-area-5").offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

I've talked with the map plugin developer and they have told me this is due to a browser limitation. They have given me some direction with the following info and code:

"The first part of that function deals with detecting if someone is trying to link to a hotspot and triggering some custom events, but below that there's a section commented for calculating where the image and area are on the page.

Basically, we had to take the coordinates set for the area and find the minimum and maximum values of the Y coordinates, and then use those to figure out how far down the page we would have to scroll to be sure the selected area was in the viewport. You'll likely have to do something similar to get scrolling to the selected hotspot to reliably display in the viewport."

```
* Link to an area */
    var linkToArea = function(){
        var hash = window.location.hash,
            area = null;

        if (!hash) return;

        if (hash) {
            area = $('area[href="' + hash + '"]');
        }

        if (!area.length) return;

        area.trigger('focus');
        area.trigger('mousedown');

        /* Calculate where the image and area are on the page */
        var map = area.parents('map'),
            mapRef = map.attr('name'),
            img = $('img[usemap="#' + mapRef + '"]'),
            imgTop = img.offset().top,
            coords = area.attr('coords').split(','),
            yCoords = [];

        for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
            if (i%2 != 0) {
                yCoords.push(coords[i]);
            }
        }

        var areaImgTop  = Math.min.apply(Math, yCoords),
            areaImgBottom = Math.max.apply(Math, yCoords),
            windowHeight = $(window).height(),
            windowBottom = imgTop + windowHeight,
            areaBottom = imgTop + areaImgBottom,
            areaTop = imgTop + areaImgTop,
            padding = 50,
            scrollCoord;

        // Scroll to the area to be sure it's in the view
        if (areaBottom > windowBottom) {
            scrollCoord = imgTop + (areaBottom - windowBottom) + padding;
            if ((areaBottom - areaTop) > windowHeight) {
                scrollCoord = areaTop - padding;
            }
        } else {
            scrollCoord = imgTop - padding;
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollCoord);
        }, 1);
    }
```

Could anyone offer some help with this? I am a bit of a loss. Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an hard one to reproduce... Can you create a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io) of that page, so one could play with it? -- I would try to use the mouseover event to find the x/y position ant the target element... But, since that is a canvas, it may be easier to say than do.

Comment: Its tough to create a CodePen due to the map functionality being handled by the WP Draw Attention plugin.

I am quickly realizing this is going to be much more difficult than I expected. If there is a better solution that using the plugin, I am all ears.

Comment: Okay... I created a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KBqzvG?editors=0010)... But before I go futher, you have an issue with directory link ids. That cannot include spaces! I made a quick mouseover function that console logs the ids... So you can see. Look to fix that first. There must be a solution then... ;)

Comment: Design-wise, consider scrolling the map independently of the page. Code-wise, store an array of units needed to scroll to the desired area then add those to your scrollTop value.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette removing the spaces from the IDs won't be a problem. I'm not quite sure how removing the spaces will solve the problem of not being able to scroll to a map area though. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick the map will scroll independently of the page, I just haven't gotten that far along yet as I Wanted to get the map working correctly first. I am not sure what you mean with the rest of your comment though.

Comment: Removing the spaces inside the id wo't fix the issue at all. I just stopped on it as my brain doesn't want to build on invalid basis... lol Actually, I don't know how to fix the main issue.

Comment: If the browser doesn't support .offset().top for an area within an image map, then if you want to scroll to a specific area you'll need to provide the distances needed.